# Software for calculating the mirror Chern number of 2D systems?

Tags: density-functional-theory, software-recommendations, one-topic-per-answer, topological-insulators, density-functional-tight-binding

Can anyone please explain to me how can I calculate the mirror Chern number of a 2D system? I will be very thankful if you can refer me to a package or software which can directly perform mirror Chern number calculations without any complex calculations. Thank you.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? If you found anything over the last 6 months, you're welcome to self-answer it!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments or anyone else wants to provide an answer.